# Finding points outside of a disk

Tags: computational-geometry, distance

Here I have a list of points on the plane:

```
lst = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {55, 2}];
```

and a disk with the radius `r=1` drawn around the point number i. i will be taken equal 5 in this example below.

I want to select all points with the distance to the disk larger than `r`. Here I am doing it:

```
    Clear[lst2, lst3, i, r];
i = 5;
r = 1;

(* This makes a list with a dropped i-th element *)
lstA = lst /. x_ /; x == lst[[i]] -> Nothing;

(* This selects a sublist from the lstA that fulfills the requirement *)
```

lst1 = Select[lstA, RegionDistance[Disk[lst[[i]], 1], #] >= 2 r &];

For the visual purpose here is a list of points that are closer than 1 to the disk:

```
lst2 = Select[lstA, RegionDistance[Disk[lst[[i]], 1], #] < 2 r &];
```

Now let us draw this, showing the points that must be closer in red, and those far - in black:

```
    Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[0.3], Disk[lst[[i]], 1], Opacity[1], Black, 
  Point[#] & /@ lst1, Red, Point[#] & /@ lst2}]
```

[image]

We see something quite unexpected. Some red points are outside it, though must be inside. 
Do I strongly miss something?

Comment: The red dots do not have to be inside: they can be outside as long as the distance to the closest point in the disk is less than `r`. From the docs of `RegionDistance`: "Region distance is effectively given by `MinValue[{Norm[p-q],q\[Element]reg},q]`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to put the correct origin in the Disk plot. And the distance should be smaler or equal otherwise you dont get point inside (with distance equal to zero).

```
lst = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {55, 2}];
Clear[lst1, lst2, i, r];
i = 5;
r = 0;

lst1 = Select[lst, RegionDistance[Disk[lst[[3]], 1], #] >= r &];

lst2 = Select[lst, RegionDistance[Disk[lst[[3]], 1], #] <= r &];

 Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[0.3], Disk[lst[[3]], 1], Opacity[1], Black, Point[#] & /@ lst1, Red, Point[#] & /@ lst2}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. I tried to remove the question, but failed

Answer (score 4):

I think `RegionMember` is what you are looking for.

```
lst = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {55, 2}];

i = 5;
r = 1;

regionDisk = Disk[lst[[i]], 1];
```

and then

```
lst2 = Select[lst, RegionMember[regionDisk, #] &]

Graphics[{
  Blue,
  Opacity[0.3],
  regionDisk,
  Opacity[1],
  Black,
  Point[lst],
  Red,
  Point[lst2]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]